# What is OData standard for odata.nextLink in case of 1:N $expand queries?

Tags: rest, odata, expand

We can see the *odata.nextlink* standard in the server driven paging for normal queries [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/pagination#server-driven-paging). But there is no *odata.nextlink* standard mentioned in case of 1:N  *$expand* queries in [$expand docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/odata-expand#expand).

Can someone please confirm OData standard for 1:N *$expand* queries please?

**Example:**
If we have multiple *account_tasks* for a single *account*, how the result should look like:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$top=1&$expand=Account_Tasks($select=subject)
```

**Option-1**: Where data is shown in list inline till the page-size, and *odata.nextLink* is shown if data count exceeds the page-size. So, odata.nextLink will show the next set of results. (Similar to standard pagination [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/pagination#server-driven-paging).)

```
{
    "@odata.context": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#accounts(name,Account_Tasks(subject,scheduledstart))",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"37867294\"",
            "name": "Contoso, Ltd. (sample)",
            "accountid": "7a4814f9-b0b8-ea11-a812-000d3a122b89",
            "Account_Tasks": [
                {
                    "@odata.etag": "W/\"28876919\"",
                    "subject": "Task 1 for Contoso, Ltd.",
                },
                {
                   // More account_tasks here. No odata.nextLink if data count < page-size.
            ]
        }
    ] 
 }
```

**Option-2**: We'll show empty results inline and provide an *odata.nextLink* to actual data.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#accounts(name,Account_Tasks(subject,scheduledstart))",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"37867294\"",
            "name": "Contoso, Ltd. (sample)",
            "accountid": "7a4814f9-b0b8-ea11-a812-000d3a122b89",
            "Account_Tasks": [], 
             // Empty list shown above and URL given below will show the full results.
            "Account_Tasks@odata.nextLink": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/accounts(7a4814f9-b0b8-ea11-a812-000d3a122b89)/Account_Tasks?$select=subject,scheduledstart"
        }
    ] 
 }
```

**Option-3**: Where data is shown in list till page-size, and *odata.nextLink* is shown every time (even if data count is smaller than the page-size). So, the *odata.nextLink* will show the full expand results including inline results.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#accounts(name,Account_Tasks(subject,scheduledstart))",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"37867294\"",
            "name": "Contoso, Ltd. (sample)",
            "accountid": "7a4814f9-b0b8-ea11-a812-000d3a122b89",
            "Account_Tasks": [
                {
                    "@odata.etag": "W/\"28876919\"",
                    "subject": "Task 1 for Contoso, Ltd.",
                },
                {
                   // More account tasks here       
            ],
            "Account_Tasks@odata.nextLink": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/accounts(7a4814f9-b0b8-ea11-a812-000d3a122b89)/Account_Tasks?$select=subject,scheduledstart"
        }
    ] 
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Good question -- paging of nested results is often misunderstood.

Nested results are paged individually, so where the nested account_tasks for a particular account exceeds a sever-defined threshold, the account_tasks up to that threshold are included, along with a nextlink to retrieve the additional account_tasks for that account. Which, I believe, is your Option 1.

Note that, since the threshold is server-defined, it is also valid to have a threshold of 0, and only include a nextlink for the nested account_tasks. However, each account will still have a different nextlink, and following that nextlink will return only those account_tasks for the account in which the nextlink was returned.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, Michael, for the answer.

Just for confirmation:
If the "results count" is less than the "server defined page size", then it won't include the odata.nextlink, right?

Comment: Correct -- if you include all of the nested account_tasks for a particular account, you wouldn't include a nextLink for that account.